# Why Aren't Variables Set In Batch File If Block?

Tags: batch-file

Believe me, I've searched around but I haven't had any joy with this seemingly innocuous problem.

**NOTE**: There are some posts and answers on SO surrounding issues with batch variables in `for` loops; it's likely that many will not realize that `if` blocks impose the same complications regarding expansion.

I'm far from a batch file aficionado, so I'm likely missing something basic, but when I run the following script:

```
set testVar1=Initial Value 1
echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
if 1==1 (
  echo In If Block
  echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
  set testVar1=In If Block
  echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
  set testVar2=Initial Value 2
  echo testVar2 = %testVar2%
)
echo Out of If Block
echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
echo testVar2 = %testVar2%
```

I get:

```
testVar1 = Initial Value 1
In If Block
testVar1 = Initial Value 1
testVar1 = Initial Value 1
testVar2 =
Out of If Block
testVar1 = In If Block
testVar2 = Initial Value 2
```

Whereas what I would expect to see is:

```
testVar1 = Initial Value 1
In If Block
testVar1 = Initial Value 1
testVar1 = In If Block
testVar2 = Initial Value 2
Out of If Block
testVar1 = In If Block
testVar2 = Initial Value 2
```

Within the `if` block, I change the value of `testVar1` but when I echo it, it has the original value. Similarly, I create a new `testVar2` variable within the `if` block but when I echo it, it has a null value.

Yet once I exit the `if` block, the values set within it are correct when echoed.

I've been very careful with spaces in declarations, as mentioned elsewhere, and I've tried several variations but the above is the most basic test I can devise to illustrate the issue.

As I said, no doubt I'm missing something obvious but I don't know what it is.

I've also tried adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` as I've seen mention of this, but it made no difference.

Comment: using delayed expansion also requires to use `!var!` instead of a `%var%` in order to expand variable's values in brackets blocks.

Comment: Weird that you could not find an answer.  All I did was put `enabledelayedexpansion` in the search box and it found a couple hundred answers.

Comment: @Squashman Yeah, if you know what to look for, you will likely find it! Both suggested duplicates focus on `for` loops; I didn't expect a simple `if` block would have this kid of impact as there is no iteration, simply an enclosing block. I've edited my question to stress this.

Comment: upvoted for your efforts to pin the problem down to the basics and a clear and understandable question.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, much appreciated! Answer is all credit to npocmaka.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, yes, my ignorance. Here's the fix, thanks to npocmaka:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansionset
testVar1=Initial Value 1
echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
if 1==1 (
  echo In If Block
  echo testVar1 = !testVar1!
  set testVar1=In If Block
  echo testVar1 = !testVar1!
  set testVar2=Initial Value 2
  echo testVar2 = !testVar2!
)
echo Out of If Block
echo testVar1 = %testVar1%
echo testVar2 = %testVar2%
```

(I hate batch files even more now!)